# divide the row into two rows after several columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have CSV file and  I try to split my row into many rows if it contains more  than 4 columns

Example:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRwcg.png)

Expected Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSS5D.png)

So there are way to do that in pandas or python

Sorry if this is a simple question

Comment: You can try: `s=df.stack(); pd.DataFrame({'x_center': s[:, 'x_center'], 'y_center': s[:, 'y_center']})` where `df` is your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

When there are two columns with the same name in CSV file, the pandas dataframe automatically appends an integer value to the duplicate column name

for example:

This CSV file :

[image]

Will become this :

```
df = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")
df
```

[image]

Now to solve your question, lets consider the above dataframe as the input dataframe.
**Try this** :

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols.remove('id')
start = 0
end = 4
new_df = []
final_cols = ['id','x1','y1','x2','y2']
while start<len(cols):
    if end>len(cols):
        end = len(cols)
    temp = cols[start:end]
    start = end
    end = end+4
    temp_df = df.loc[:,['id']+temp]
    temp_df.columns = final_cols[:1+len(temp)]

    if len(temp)<4:
        temp_df[final_cols[1+len(temp):]] = None
    
    print(temp_df)
        
    new_df.append(temp_df)

pd.concat(new_df).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can first set the `video` column as index then concat your remaining every 4 columns into a new dataframe. At last, reset index to get `video` column back.

```py
df.set_index('video', inplace=True)

dfs = []
for i in range(len(df.columns)//4):
    d = df.iloc[:, range(i*4,i*4+4)]
    dfs.append(d.set_axis(['x_center', 'y_center']*2, axis=1))

df_ = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index()
```

I think the following list comprehension should work, but it gives an positional indexing error on my machine and I don't know why

```
df_ = pd.concat([df.iloc[: range(i*4, i*4+4)].set_axis(['x_center', 'y_center']*2, axis=1) for i in range(len(df.columns)//4)])
```

```
print(df_)

  video   x_center   y_center   x_center   y_center
0   1_1  31.510973  22.610222  31.383655  22.488293
1   1_1  31.856295  22.830109  32.016905  22.948702
2   1_1  32.011684  22.990689  31.933356  23.004779
```